# Parse JSON object with numeric value as type

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to JSON and trying to understand how to traverse a structure I get from a query in Javascript. I want to get the fullurl value.

I can manage to get to query.pages but not sure what to do when I have to navigate "4187783".

I been looking around for a solution for a while. Appreciate the help!

```
{
 "batchcomplete":"",
 "query":{
  "pages":{
   "418783":{
    "pageid":418783,
    "ns":0,
    "title":"San Francisco LGBT Community Center",
    "contentmodel":"wikitext",
    "pagelanguage":"en",
    "touched":"2015-09-21T09:58:52Z",
    "lastrevid":675179151,
    "length":2449,
    "fullurl":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_LGBT_Community_Center"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can manage to get to query.pages but not sure what to do when I have to navigate "4187783".

`query.pages["4187783"]`

For the fullurl:
`query.pages["4187783"].fullurl`

Comment: Hi Chris, the number is actually a number so you need to remove the quotes.

Comment: @Saar agree, although some browsers support both ways due the key casting

Answer (score 2):

First transform your JSON string into an object:

```
var result = JSON.parse(yourJson);
```

now you can do the following:

```
var fullUrl = result.query.pages[418783].fullurl;
// you can replace 418783 with "length" or "contentmodel" to get other properties.
```